# Homebrew, Java, OpenCV, OSX setup

Tags: java, macos, opencv, homebrew

I seem to be having great difficulty in setting up OpenCV for use with Java. I've build the OpenCV library using HomeBrew (with the java flag). It has build a .JAR file which seems fine. However I've now tried using Eclipse, IntelliJ and Netbeans but can't seem to get OpenCV working with any of them.

I get the code completion and import completion in all IDE's however when it comes to run time, I get a linker error saying something like the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java2412 in java.library.path
```

Can anyone help me with getting this working in any IDE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow this [example](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html) you can make it work.

I follow it and execute with this line and work for me.

ant -DocvJarDir=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/share/OpenCV/java/ -DocvLibDir=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/share/OpenCV/java

In any case you add the following flag to your jvm runtime parameters:

-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/share/OpenCV/java

Of course that point to my path of OpenCV in my homebrew.

Let me know if it work for you.

Comment: Happy to help. This is my first answer :)